# ServletException or IOException?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, ioexception, servletexception

...I never can decide between these two. I'm always going back to the code and switching between.

When you're coding - let's say a Login class - from an (extended) HttpServlet, which sports both ServletException and IOException, and you just want to throw further your exception (e.g. NoSuchAlgorithmException, NamingException) to see it in a page of your application later, which one do you throw it through: ServletException or IOException?

*P.S.: I don't try to catch every possible NoSuchAlgorithmException, NamingException, etc. because I can miss a real cause that I haven't seen before and treat it the wrong way or inform the wrong thing to the user.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IOException` has its own meaning. An `IOException` should be only thrown when there as an issue in IO operations e.g. reading/writing data from file or URL. If I have to make choice between the two, I will choose `ServletExcetion`.

But if there is a room to define better exception handling then I would like to create my own custom exception class e.g. `MySystemException` extending `RuntimeException` and wrap the relevant exceptions as `MySystemException` and throw it.

Comment: In my example with the Login class, isn't this whole step an IO due to the user inputting credentials? Or IOException is not made for that?

Comment: @Andrysse: If your `Login` class is reading the user's input directly from the input device, then there could be an IOException but in server  based applications, that is not the case. **You capture the user input in the client side and then pass the input as parameter to the server component**. In that case, it will not be an `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these, just inherit from `RuntimeException` or another exception that inherits from `RuntimeException` as `IllegalArgumentException`.